# What is the best way to import a GraphML or GraphSON file into Neo4j in ruby?

Tags: ruby, neo4j, graphml

I am using jruby-1.7.6 and neo4j 2.0.1.

There is a [Pacer Gem](https://github.com/pangloss/pacer) and [pacer-neo4j gem](https://github.com/pangloss/pacer-neo4j) that provides

```
Pacer::GraphML.import
```

which can be used to import GraphML file into neo4j.

What to do about GraphSON file? What are other options to Is pacer only way to import GraphML file to neo4j through ruby?

Answer (score 0):

You can also import graphml with the [shell import tools](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools#graphml-import), which works independent of any programming language.

For GraphSON you can probably just pass the GraphSON-JSON Map to Cypher directly and use the map + collection support to import the details?

See for an ruby example of some JSON: https://gist.github.com/jexp/3b60a3a1f29061853e8c